# uiviewcontroller don't respond

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a view, with a navigationBar on top. I add a subview in this view. My subview is a view with a toolBar.

```
SecondView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 418, 320, 42);

[principalView addSubview:SecondView];
[principalView bringSubviewToFront:SecondView];
```

After that, the subView is in my principalView, at the right place, but when I click in the subView, nothing happen.

But, if my navigationBar is like this, all works perfectly,

self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle =  UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

Why the subview do nothing if my navigationBarStyle is UIBarStyleDefault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `SecondView` has fallen out of your `principalView` bounds. If that's the case, it will still be visible because principalView does not clip subviews, but `SecondView` will not respond to user action. You should check the `principalView.bounds` property against `SecondView.frame`.

Comment: the property bounds is in IB or I set this programmaticaly.

Comment: I set the bounds property or my principalView to 0,0,320,460 but I have the same problem...

Comment: Could you try setting your principalView.backgroundColor to [UIColor redColor] or some color, and set your toolbar frame a little bit smaller, and check it again?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just using Interface Builder to do this. Also, normally you don't use navigation bars by themselves. Normally if you have a navigation bar you should use a `UINavigationController` and push view controllers onto that.